# How get url from WebView(youtube.com) in pcl-project when click video?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

How current get url from WebView(youtube.com) in pcl-project when click video?

I need to save the latest link on click user.

Check two method...
   WebView_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
   WevView_Navigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
In these methods, only the previous values can be obtained URL(.

I tried to use WebViewRenderer  but ShouldOverrideUrlLoading not call.
Perhaps because method obsolete.

Comment: please edit your question,

Comment: Are you running this in Android?